# How to readjust the list (dropdown), replicating the original codes of options selector in React JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, gatsby

I am still learning JavaScript, React and GatsbyJS.

I have difficult to readjust the list (dropdown (`ul > li > input label > ul > li`), replicating the original codes of @Smakosh's [`gatsby-starter-i18n/src/components/theme/Header/SelectLanguage.jsx`](https://github.com/smakosh/gatsby-starter-i18n/blob/master/src/components/theme/Header/SelectLanguage.jsx) which is options selection (`select > option`) because of `value={lang} onChange={e => selectLanguage(e.target.value)}` that the list does not have. I wanted to use `data-aria`, but I do not use Bootstrap and jQuery.

- The original codes of [`gatsby-starter-i18n/src/components/theme/Header/SelectLanguage.jsx`](https://github.com/smakosh/gatsby-starter-i18n/blob/master/src/components/theme/Header/SelectLanguage.jsx):

  ```
  const SelectLanguage = ({ selectLanguage, lang }) => (
    <select value={lang} onChange={e => selectLanguage(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="es">Español</option>
      <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
      <option value="ar">عربي</option>
      <option value="pt">Português</option>
    </select>
  )
  ```

  I tried to readjust it to the list (dropdown) based on https://codepen.io/Tont/pen/hdsev:

  ```
  const SelectLanguage = ({ selectLanguage, lang }) => (
    <li>
        <Input id="languages" type="checkbox" name="menu" href={lang} onChange={e => selectLanguage(e.target.value)}/>
        <Label for="languages">Languages</Label>
        <Submenu className="submenu">
          <li><a href="en">English</a></li>
          <li><a href="es">Español</a></li>
        </Submenu>
    </li>

  )
  ```
- The original codes of [`gatsby-starter-i18n/blob/master/src/components/theme/Header/index.jsx`](https://github.com/smakosh/gatsby-starter-i18n/blob/master/src/components/theme/Header/index.jsx):

  ```
  const Header = () => (
    <Context.Consumer>
        {({ toggleLanguage, lang }) => (
            <StyledHeader>
                <Navbar as={Container}>
                    <Links>
              {/* ... */}
                        <SelectLanguage lang={lang} toggleLanguage={toggleLanguage} />
                    </Links>
                </Navbar>
            </StyledHeader>
        )}
    </Context.Consumer>
  )
  ```

  I changed the codes based on that pen:

  ```
  const Header = () => (
    <Context.Consumer>
      {({ toggleLanguage, lang }) => (
        <StyledHeader>
          <Navegador id="menu">
            <li>
              <Links>
                {/* ... */}
                <SelectLanguage lang={lang} toggleLanguage={toggleLanguage} />
              </Links>
            </li>
          </Navegador>
        </StyledHeader>
      )}
    </Context.Consumer>
  )
  ```

#### Source

- @Smakosh's [Gatsby Starer i18n](https://github.com/smakosh/gatsby-starter-i18n)

  - [`theme/Header/SelectLanguage.jsx`](https://github.com/smakosh/gatsby-starter-i18n/blob/master/src/components/theme/Header/SelectLanguage.jsx)
  - [`theme/Header/index.jsx`](https://github.com/smakosh/gatsby-starter-i18n/blob/master/src/components/theme/Header/index.jsx)
- [Pure CSS Click Dropdowm Menu](https://codepen.io/Tont/pen/hdsev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never worked with Gatsby or recompose before, so I doubt if I can be of much help, but I'll give it a go and let you know what I think might be the problem anyway:

From what I see, the value of the languages input is being sent whenever it is clicked, but I can't see that value updated with the language selected, whenever the list items are clicked, so this is how I would approach it

```
const SelectLanguage = ({ selectLanguage, lang }) => (
  <li>
      <Input id="languages" type="checkbox" name="menu" />
      <Label for="languages">Languages</Label>
      <Submenu className="submenu">
        <li onClick={e => selectLanguage("en")} ><a href="en">English</a></li>
        <li onClick={e => selectLanguage("es")}><a href="es">Español</a></li>
      </Submenu>
  </li>

)
```